# unable to scan a long barcode

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am unable to scan the following barcode image on Android:

[image: barcode]

It encodes a 13-15 digit number and using an online barcode reader gives the type as `CODE_39`.

Is there any specific way to handle reading such barcodes on Android?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393710/how-to-read-code-39-using-zxing-in-android   .....might this will help you

Comment: What scanner packages are you attempting to use? Do you have a specific error message that you're getting when attempting to scan? It will help us if you post some of your code you're currently using to scan the barcode.

Comment: I'm not sure of the reason since I'm unable to scan it using even using apps such as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qrcodescanner.barcodescanner

Comment: @GhostCat I am myself unsure of the reason and am looking for a helpful explanation.

Comment: The problem is: it is not even clear if you talk about a *programming* problem.

Comment: @GhostCat I am not sure here but is it because of a violation of the quiet zone in the barcode image provided in the question?

Comment: This community is about **programming** problems. Do you have a problem with code you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need to zoom out a bit by moving your camera away. I'm not entirely sure though.

Comment: Glad it works, I don't have an android, so I was just guessing.